# Capturing the order of events in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to figure out a way to capture and count the drug order based on a month number for each patient id. ID to Tag is one to one relationship. Basically for each year i want to count the number of drug paths for each patient and sum them, grouped by Tag. Drug Path is determined by going from lower months to higher months. There can also be more then 2 drugs in a path.
Here are the example input and output.

I am using SSMS.

Input:

| Year | Month | ID | Drug | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020/21 | 3 | 127 | E | O |
| 2020/21 | 5 | 127 | E | O |
| 2020/21 | 7 | 127 | E | O |
| 2020/21 | 10 | 127 | L | O |
| 2020/21 | 3 | 121 | A | S |
| 2020/21 | 5 | 121 | A | S |
| 2020/21 | 6 | 121 | A | S |
| 2020/21 | 9 | 111 | A | D |
| 2020/21 | 10 | 111 | A | D |
| 2020/21 | 12 | 111 | L | D |
| 2020/21 | 8 | 110 | E | O |
| 2020/21 | 9 | 110 | L | O |
| 2020/21 | 5 | 10 | A | O |
| 2021/22 | 3 | 127 | E | O |
| 2021/22 | 5 | 127 | E | O |
| 2021/22 | 7 | 127 | E | O |
| 2021/22 | 10 | 127 | L | O |
| 2021/22 | 3 | 121 | A | S |
| 2021/22 | 5 | 121 | A | S |
| 2021/22 | 6 | 121 | A | S |
| 2021/22 | 9 | 111 | A | D |
| 2021/22 | 10 | 111 | A | D |
| 2021/22 | 12 | 111 | L | D |
| 2021/22 | 8 | 110 | E | O |
| 2021/22 | 9 | 110 | E | O |
| 2021/22 | 5 | 19 | E | O |
| 2021/22 | 7 | 91 | E | S |

Expected Output:

| Year | Drug Order | Count | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020/21 | E-->L | 2 | O |
| 2020/21 | A | 1 | S |
| 2020/21 | A-->L | 1 | D |
| 2020/21 | A | 1 | O |
| 2021/22 | E-->L | 1 | O |
| 2021/22 | A | 1 | S |
| 2021/22 | A-->L | 1 | D |
| 2021/22 | E | 2 | O |
| 2021/22 | E | 1 | S |

Comment: SSMS is purely a client UI, and is not usually relevant to the question. You are using SQL Server as your RDBMS... that is relevant, as is the version `select @@version`.

Comment: Added version number

Comment: Well i have solved the question using python/pandas, you are welcome to ignore the question if you do not have anything relevant to add.

Comment: A solution in SQL looks to require a *gaps and islands* approach, but I can't see anything in your data that can reliably be used to order your rows.

Comment: @Stu The ordering is based on Month (ascending order)

Comment: The month only orders rows within each Tag group but you need to identify multiple groups (islands), there must be a row Id or PK column you're not including?

Comment: @Stu i am not sure gaps and island approach will work. We don't need any other info to get the output. For example in the expected output, first row count (=2) for E--> L belongs to ID 127 and 110, as these 2 patients switched from E to L. It doesn't matter where the respective rows are in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
With CTE AS(
  Select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By ID,Year,Tag Order By Year, Month) mn_rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By ID,Year,Tag Order By Year DESC, Month DESC) mx_rn
  From datatable
),
CTE2 As
(
  Select *, MIN(Case When mn_rn = 1 Then Drug End) Over (Partition By ID,Year,Tag) from_d,
         MAX(Case When mx_rn = 1 Then Drug End) Over (Partition By ID,Year,Tag) to_d from cte
  Where mn_rn =1 or mx_rn=1
)
Select Year, (from_d + Case When from_d<>to_d then '->' + to_d Else '' End) [Drug Order],
       COUNT(Distinct ID) [Count], Tag
From CTE2
Group By Year, from_d, to_d, Tag
Order By Year
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fe54c63066c3511c1fa580c7ac91327).

Update, to include the intermediate drug values within the drug order:

```
With CTE AS(
  Select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By ID,Year,Tag Order By Year, Month) -
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By ID,Year,Tag,drug Order By Year, Month) grp
  From datatable
),
CTE2 As
(
  Select *,
         STUFF((Select N'->' + MAX(T.Drug) From cte T Where T.id = D.id and T.year = D.year And T.tag = D.tag 
         Group By T.id,T.year,T.tag,T.grp,T.drug Order by max(t.month) 
         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'),1, 2, N'') drug_order
  from cte D
 )
Select Year,  drug_order [Drug Order],
       COUNT(Distinct ID) [Count], Tag
From CTE2
Group By Year,Tag,drug_order
Order By Year
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=798955a63ee0cb2fc80f127b59137a41).

Comment: Thanks. Close but doesn't quite work. Lets say i add one more record for ID 111 (('2021/22',12,111,'A','D'); so 111 switched back to A in month 12,  so one of the output row should be drug order: A-->L-->A with count 1.

Comment: When adding that row, what should the output be? check this for id=111 after adding that row.    https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d5cee547564434a7f28d4ddc4b165a2

Comment: So you want to include the intermediate drug values, not only from/ to?

Comment: Yes intermediate values too.

Comment: I updated the answer, but when adding ('2021/22',12,111,'A','D') you will have two drugs within the same month, so in the fiddle I changed the month to 11 for the row ('2021/22',12,111,'L','D')

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works but taking too long to run on my dataset :) Trying to optimize the query.

Comment: Maybe you need to add some indexes to your table, check this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186567/optimizing-query-for-xml-path-or-some-alternatives